# ReactJS Binding invalid left-hand side in function parameter list

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I need to filter out top 5 objects in a list based on their count. So I decided to sort them first. Here's the list

```
myList=[
   {name: "name1", count: 12},
   {name: "name2", count: 8},
   {name: "name3", count: 42},
   {name: "name4", count: 22},
   {name: "name5", count: 0},
   {name: "name6", count: 18},
   {name: "name7", count: 0},
   {name: "name8", count: 1},
]
```

And this is my sorting code

```
SortData = () => {
        let data1 = [...this.state.myList]
        data1.sort((a - b) => {
            return a.count - b.count
        })
    }
```

However, I am getting an error in React as

```
SyntaxError: Binding invalid left-hand side in function parameter list   
at data1.sort((a-b) => {
               ^
```

I am not able to figure out what's wrong. Can someone please help with a code to sort the list based on count and also filter out the top 5. Thanks

Comment: it's a simple error, change it to this `data1.sort((a,b) => {`

Comment: Oh geez how silly of me! Thank you!!

Answer (score 3):

You should pass 2 param in call back of sort function.

```
SortData = () => {
        let data1 = [...this.state.myList]
        data1.sort((a, b) => {
            return a.count - b.count
        })
    }
```